# This programs takes a long time to close after the 'return;' on main()

Tags: c++, performance, destructor

This is the code I am dealing with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

static unsigned long collatzLength(unsigned long n) {
    static std::map<unsigned long,int> collatzMap;
    int mapResult = collatzMap[n];
    if (mapResult != 0) return mapResult;

    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else { 
        collatzMap[n] = 1 + collatzLength(n%2==0?n/2:3*n+1);
        return collatzMap[n];
    }
}

int main() {
    int maxIndex = 1;
    unsigned int max = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<1000000; i++) {
        //cout<<i<<endl;
        unsigned long count = collatzLength(i);
        if (count > max) {
            maxIndex = i;
            max = count;
        }
    }
    cout<<maxIndex<<endl;
    getchar();
    cout<<"Returning..."<<endl;
    return maxIndex;
}
```

When I compile and run this program (using Visual Studio 2012 and Release build settings) it takes like 10 seconds (on my computer) to close after the program prints "Returning..."

Why is that?

Note: I am aware that this program is bad written and that i probably shouldn't be using 'static' on the collatzLength nor using a cache for that function, but I am not interesting on how to make this code better, I am just interesting about why does it take so much to close.

Comment: How long does it take to run in the first place? Also, it might be interesting to print out the size of `collatzMap` every once in a while. Most likely it's the destructor carefully deallocating every single node that's taking so long.

Comment: The final size of collatzMap is about 2,162,685. The hole program takes about 50secs to run in my machine

Comment: Try running the release target.  If the debug is slow, it just may be extra security that Visual Studio implements that isn't actually necessary in the release. (Basically a different way to say what SEbastian Redl said)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to project settings on your start up project, Debugging section. Enter `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` into the `Environment` section. You need to do this even in Release mode.

Answer (score 2):

It takes so long to close because `collatzMap` is `static`, thus it will only get freed when the program exits, and it contains a lot of data, so it will take long to get freed (the size is just over 2 million, and, because of how `map` works, for each of these there's at least one pointer that needs to be freed).

That said, on Dev-C++ it takes less than a second to exit. I guess Visual Studio isn't doing a good job.

Comment: It does seem a bit long, but I can't see another explanation.

Comment: Visual Studio is probably in Debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Destroying a `std::map` is very slow on Visual Studio, especially for Debug builds. The slowdown should already disappear by using an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead.

VS's implementation of map builds a red-black tree for storing the data, which means you will have to allocate a lot of tree nodes to store all your data. The limiting factor during destruction is the time required for traversing the tree and de-allocating all the nodes. With an `unordered_map` the traversal is usually a lot easier as the allocated buckets are usually larger and not as scattered as the red-black tree nodes (your mileage may vary though).

Comment: Can you elaborate why?

Comment: I see no difference using unordered_map (the program does run faster, but still takes a long time to close) Also I am using Release build

Comment: This maybe true, but changing the underlying data structure shouldn't really be a viable option.  `unordered_map` behaves similar to a map, but you have to implement hash functions, and it may not be the ideal data structure to use in Trollkemada's implementation.

Comment: @AngeloGeels Tried to elaborate a bit.

Comment: @KirkBackus True, in many cases switching to a hash map is undesirable. However, at least with VS's implementation you cannot really get around the long destruction times for map. Since it's a static object anyway, you could always allocate the map on the heap and just leak it to avoid the delay (although that of course brings its own drawbacks).

Comment: @ComicSansMS Look at my answer for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried on my machine with VS 2012 release build. It doesn't take more than 2 seconds to close the program after "Returning"

Answer (score -2):

<strike>When running VS in Debug mode, there are a lot of error checking flags set (e.g. bounds checking, memory watching, etc.)  Since you are creating a lot of data recursively in a static map, it is scanning the memory before it is released to make sure nothing was corrupted.  When you switch to a Release build, it should be almost instant.</strike>

Upon further inspection, you are basically allocating almost 1 million pairs of (`unsigned long`, `int`) in the static portion of memory.  This effectively means that ~8MB of data must be freed before the application can finish closing (and since `map` isn't required to be contiguous, it must iterate through all 1 million pairs to delete each one).  Other implementations may optimize memory usage a bit by reserving chunks of space (if it reserved enough space for say, 100 pairs, it would decrease the deallocation process by 2 orders of magnitude).

All that said, asking why bad code behaves badly is like asking why you get wet when you jump in a pool.

Comment: As I have already said both in the original question and in some comments, I am using Release build.

Comment: I missed that part in all of that bad code.  I'll adjust now that I've actually gone through and debugged it ...

Comment: Wow, using `std::map` is bad code?  Maybe it should be removed from the standard library then?

Comment: @ebyrob No, the container itself is fine; it is the misuse of it that is bad.  A hammer is a wonderful tool, but it is terrible when you need to make a precise cut.